# Getting "java.lang.RuntimeException: here" while starting application

Tags: android

There is some strange exception with text "java.lang.RuntimeException: here" in "com.android.server.pm.Settings.setPackageStoppedStateLPw", and in source file of "com.android.server.pm.Settings" I can see, that exception can be only when DEBUG_STOPPED == true. What does it mean and how i can change this behavior?

```
I/PackageSettings(  487): Stopping package com.packages.MyPackage
I/PackageSettings(  487): java.lang.RuntimeException: here
I/PackageSettings(  487):       at com.android.server.pm.Settings.setPackageStoppedStateLPw(Settings.java:2478)
I/PackageSettings(  487):       at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.setPackageStoppedState(PackageManagerService.java:9399)
I/PackageSettings(  487):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.forceStopPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:4069)
I/PackageSettings(  487):       at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:1258)
I/PackageSettings(  487):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1833)
I/PackageSettings(  487):       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
I/PackageSettings(  487):       at com.android.server.SystemServer.init1(Native Method)
I/PackageSettings(  487):       at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1306)
I/PackageSettings(  487):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
I/PackageSettings(  487):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
I/PackageSettings(  487):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
I/PackageSettings(  487):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
I/PackageSettings(  487):       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/ActivityManager(  487): Force stopping package package com.packages.MyPackage appid=10075 user=0
I/ActivityManager(  487): Killing proc 758:package com.packages.MyPackage/u0a10075: force stop package com.packages.MyPackage
```

I think, that it may be connected with unusual android firmware ...